# In NixOS, how can I resolve a collision?

Tags: python, nix, nixpkgs

I'm trying to set up a development environment with Python, including the Python libraries Spacy and Pandas. The command I'm trying to run is `nix-shell -p 'python36.withPackages(ps: with ps; [ spacy pandas ])'`

But this is what happens:

```
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/7pgb52aa5hkgzv0mkc3jmxdhavxdr013-python3-3.6.6-env.drv
building '/nix/store/7pgb52aa5hkgzv0mkc3jmxdhavxdr013-python3-3.6.6-env.drv'...
collision between `/nix/store/k1njxvw8rdv29yz7iccr4nbfwcbghwhc-python3.6-msgpack-0.5.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msgpack/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc' and `/nix/store/nig71x1wc7b3c04hs6vz8kk6bmdz5ldv-python3.6-msgpack-python-0.5.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msgpack/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc'
```

What's happening here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: when this happened to me, it was because two packages had the same hash (one was wrong)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`msgpack-python` was renamed to `msgpack` but both packages exist in `release-18.09` of Nixpkgs. This seems to have been [fixed](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/search?q=msgpack-python&type=Commits) on `master` and these fixes should be backported to 18.09. A workaround for this kind of problem does exist:

```
(python36.withPackages(ps: with ps; [ spacy pandas ])).override (args: { ignoreCollisions = true; })
```

This is not actually a NixOS problem, but a Nixpkgs problem.

Note that you can only *install* a single environment, which is another common cause of collision errors. This is not the problem here.

[I have created an issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/48864)